# Google Play Install Referrer Library - Referrer Generation

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, install-referrer

I'm developing an android application in Java where I need to pass the referer information to an URL. I'm getting the referrer information using [Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library).

Here is my code:

```
InstallReferrerClient referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build();
    referrerClient.startConnection(new InstallReferrerStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(int responseCode) {
            switch (responseCode) {
                case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK:
                    try {
                        Log.v("TAG", "InstallReferrer conneceted");
                        ReferrerDetails response = referrerClient.getInstallReferrer();
                        System.out.println("referrerUrl ID: " + response);
                        referrerClient.endConnection();
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                    Log.w("TAG", "InstallReferrer not supported");
                    break;
                case InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.w("TAG", "Unable to connect to the service");
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.w("TAG", "responseCode not found.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    });
```

Code is working fine and currently, the above snippet is inside my activity's `onCreate` method. which means it will start the new connection every time the user opens the activity.

In the [library documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library#install-referrer), they have written that

> Caution: The install referrer information will be available for 90
> days and won't change unless the application is reinstalled. To avoid
> unnecessary API calls in your app, you should invoke the API only once
> during the first execution after install.

**This is where I'm stuck**, should I just call this thing when the application starts the first time?
If yes, I can store this referrer in the shared preference, but then how will I able to know that 90 days have been passed and I need to trigger that action again? Or it there something else that should I need to implement? Kindly help me with this issue.